# Sharepoint list browsable through windows explorer in a computer but not in another computer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, explorer-view, open-with-explorer

I have a sharepoint (2013) list where I have the permissions (designer). I can browse the sharepoint directory from my computer such as (\comp_name\directory\list) through windows explorer. I cannot browse the same list from another computer.

The computer that works is running windows 7 enterprise edition and IE8. The computer that does not work is Windows Server 2008 R2 No SP, and IE8.

What port does windows explorer use when exploring the sharepoint site? Could this be a firewall or sharepoint issue?

Comment: what error you are getting on windows server? try to disable the firewall on the server then try ti

Comment: their is hotfix for windows server 2008 R2, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846960

Comment: No error. Just saying cannot access. 0x80004005 I believe error code. Disable IE Enhanced Security, Disabled firewall on the local computer still same error.

Comment: That's weird. Error code changed after playing with it 0x80070035 Network path not found . That happens after windows firewall is enabled. When it is not enabled I get 0x80004005.

Comment: did you check the hot fix?

Comment: I did but it pertains to IE 10. I am not using IE 10. IE 8 believe it or not is still in use by IT.

Comment: Have you installed desktop experience on the server2008 machine?

Comment: have you tried to "Edit" the file? This makes a mapping that you can use that path. Also, add the site to the trusted sites in your IE options.

Comment: I have found it. It was the WebClient that was missing. The IT did not install the desktop experience which apparently bundles the WebClient. Webclient supports the WebDAV extension and hence I am getting this weird error. I put this as a comment since I am trying to get IT to install it so I can verify it. Of course, over where I work, that requires months of agonizing wait and weird talks such as, is this a security risk?

Comment: In larger organizations any configuration change has to be assessed for security risks unfortunately -- which is why developing off of the production network is often easier!

Comment: I am talking about non-production environment. I need to install in the test environment. They wanted me to get a document and have it approved before installing in test environment :)

Comment: Haha -- isn't that why test environments are completely isolated from the production environment? to test stuff? I feel your pain though, I work in the govt sector :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments in the original question, I believe the answer is installing the desktop experience on the server 2008 machine. This solved the same problem for me in a VM dev environment.